# How to overlay object with transparent color in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aal9X.jpg)

I will try to explain my question according the image. Firstly i use Python3 and OpenCV3. I just want to colorize the white pixels of mask(for example with shinny blue). Then using addWeighted, i want to blend that mask onto original image. But the problem i can't colorize the mask. Mask is the result of inRange fuction and i can't transform it to RGB.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ-bpfdWQh8

Just like in the video but single frame.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick mask visualization, try this:

```
debug_img = img/2 + mask/2
```

If `img` isn't grayscale already, replace `img` with `img.mean(axis=2)` or use `cvtColor()`.

Another way is to use indexing:

```
debug_img = img.copy()
debug_img[mask>0] = (0, 255, 0) # replace masked pixels with green
```

To make the green transparent, simply add

```
debug_img = debug_img/2 + img/2
```